# How to get the result of random choice on separate lines?

Tags: python, random, input

I want the random values ​​to be in a separate row, but I don't know how I can do it.

```
 import random
 d='2'
 g='3' 
 sz='4' 
 s='5'
 dd=input(random.sample([d,g,sz,s], k=4))
```

Desired output:

```
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'\n'.join()` for that.

```py
import random
d='2'
g='3'
sz='4'
s='5'
dd= random.sample([d,g,sz,s], k=4)

print('\n'.join(dd))
```

```py
5 
3
4
2
```